# Flex :Do all continaers inherit all properties of UIComponent and Container

Tags: apache-flex, flex3

Being subclasses of Continaer which is again subclass of UIcomponent, do all container in flex 'inherit all properties of UIcomponent and Container' ? Is there any exception to this rule ?

Please help me on this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Being subclasses of Continaer which is
>   again subclass of UIcomponent, do all
>   container in flex 'inherit all
>   properties of UIcomponent and
>   Container' ?

Yes! Assuming of course that the container in question is actually a child of UIComponent and/or Container.  I have made components that only extend UIComponent, for example.  They would not have any container specific properties [unless they were implemented on their own independent of the container implementation].

> Is there any exception to this rule ?

No, however, subclasses can override properties and implement them differently.  They can also use metadata to remove properties from mxml code hinting. You can still set these propeties in ActionScript, although if they are being excluded there is probably a reason why that relates tot he component's functionality.